# Weighted Degree Distribution in Python's graph_tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

In Pythons [graph_tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/), is there an easy way to calculate the weighted degree distribution (sum of the weights on out-going, in-coming, or all edges)?

In the **Stats** package, **vertex_hist** gives the un-weighted in-degree, out-degree, and total-degree histograms, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the weighted version of these.

Note: I am working with 31,000 vertices and >10 million edges. I am looking for a way to do this utilizing graph_tool as as much as possible.

Comment: What is Python's "graph_tool"?  Are you using networkx?

Comment: http://graph-tool.skewed.de/

Comment: You ask, "Is there an easy way" but then say "I know there are easy ways of doing this"? Then what are they and what's lacking in their efficiency?

Comment: You are right, poor wording on my part. I re-worded it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is easy. You have to obtain a property map of the weighted degrees, and then do a histogram:

```
d = g.degree_property_map("out", weight)   # weight is an edge property map
bins = linspace(d.a.min(), d.a.max(), 40)  # linear bins
h = vertex_hist(g, d, bins)
```